# Vue ,listen to route param change but not child route change?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router

I have the following structure in vue.js ,using `vue-router`.

```
routes: [

    {
      path: '/domains',
      component: ListOfDomains
    },

    {
      path: '/domain/:domainName',
      component: Domain,
      children: [{

          // Photos Tab content will be rendered inside domain's  <router-view>
          // when /domain/:id/photos is matched
          path: 'posts', 
          name: 'posts',
          component: PostsTabContent
        },
        {
          path: 'photos',
          name: 'photos',
          component:PhotosTabContent
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
```

In my Domain component I use a watcher to fetch domain related data from server such as:

```
"$route": function(to, from) {
      console.log("watcher triggered");
      //do  update only if domain has changed
      //do something , ajax request , update store etc

    }
```

This seems to work fine, but my problem is that I only want to do my updates if the url changes from, say, `domain/domain23/posts to domain/domain45/posts` and not when it changes from `domain/domain23/posts` to `domain/domain23/photos`. 
How can I watch only that level in the route for changes?

Comment: Just a quick guess: can you watch on `$route.params.domainName` ?

Comment: @ThomasKleßen Thanks it works . But is this the correct way of doing it ?. Or is there any other best practise for handling such cases in vue router?

Comment: As far as i know this is the best solution because you can not use the lifecyle hooks for this task.